# Comparaison of two version of Fractional sobolev spaces: what do we have $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

There are two version of Fractional sobolev spaces .

**Definition1: (Via Galiardo semi-norm)** Let $1\leq p\leq +\infty$, $0<s<1$ and $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set. The [fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567412/fractional-sobolev-spaces-are-banach-spaces) is defined to be

$$ W^{s,p}(\Omega) = \left\{ u\in L^p(\Omega) : \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{n}{p} + s}} \in L^p(\Omega\times\Omega) \right\} $$

equipped with the norm

$$ \|u\|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)} = \left( \int_\Omega |u|^p \; dx + \int_\Omega\int_\Omega \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+ sp}} \; dx dy \right)^{1/p}. $$

**Definition2:(Via Fourier Transform)**
For $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $1<p<\infty$, and $n\geq 1$, define the [Sobolev space $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572826/ws-p-mathbbrn-is-not-closed-under-multiplication-when-s-leq-n-p) by
    $$H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n}):=\left\{f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) : \|(\langle{\xi}\rangle^{s}\widehat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{p}}<\infty\right\}$$,
equipped with norm
    $$\|f\|_{H^{s,p}}=\|(\langle{\xi}\rangle^{s}\widehat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{p}}$$

Where, $$\langle{\xi}\rangle^{s} =(1+|\xi|^2)^s$$

From these definitions I have a couples of questions

> 1) What are the value of $p\in[1,\infty)$ such that $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ coincide?

I have found that this true for $p=2$ that is $$W^{s,2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=H^{s,2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$$

> Do we still have equality or one side inclusion for some $p\neq 2$ if yes which one ? if no please provide me with some counter example or reference.

2) Next I would like to  know what are the advantage and disadvantage using one   the spaces  $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

I know that  the definition $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$
makes sense on any domain  which not the case for $H^{s,p}(\Omega)$ due to the lack of Fourier transforms.

Comment: But you can easily construct $H^{s,p}(\Omega)$ spaces. (By the way, these are usually called "Bessel potential spaces" when $p\ne 2$). This is done for example in the book on wave equations by Struwe.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think the Bessel potential is already implicitly involve in the definition of $H^{s,p}$

Comment: Yes, that's true. I mean, if you do an Internet search try using the keyword "Bessel potential", you should find the answers you are looking for.

Comment: This seems to be basically the same as the question you posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288619/comparaison-of-two-version-of-fractional-sobolev-spaces-what-do-we-have-ws-p
In my opinion, [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice about cross-posting. Of course, you might have a look also at other discussions on meta about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: I also wrote an answer to a similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709099/is-bs-p-p-ws-p